# What is the index clustering factor of and index organize table

Tags: oracle11g, indexing

If I get well the description from Oracle, the [Index Clustering Factor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm) is an indicator to know if physical odering of the rows is close to the one given by the index. So you won't need to read one physical block per row when you perform a full scan.

But when the data is stored withing the index structure, in [Index Organized Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/indexiot.htm#autoId21), isn't the clustering factor simply 0?

Running `select INDEX_NAME, CLUSTERING_FACTOR FROM ALL_INDEXES` Oracle gives me a non zero clustering factor for my main IOTable index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clustering factor number is calculated by imagining a full scan of the index, in the order of the indexed values, and counting the number of times that the block from which the current row would be read is different to the block from which the previous row is fetched (there's a 12c (I think) enhancement that extends this beyond the previous 1 value).

So in a disordered table each row is likely to be found in a different block to the prior one. In an ordered table it is likely to be in the same block.

Therefore the minimum clustering factor is generally equal to the number of blocks in the table, and the maximum is generally equal to the number of rows in the table.

For an IOT, the clustering factor for the IOT index (not the secondary indexes) is threfore likely to be the same as the number of blocks for the table (excluding overflow).